# Get the Application Package name in template Wizard recipe class Intellij

Tags: android, android-studio, templates, intellij-plugin, package-name

> Get the Application Package name in template recipe class

- I am working on [MVVM plugin template](https://github.com/MuhammadIbrahim001/MVVMTemplate) for android studio. I completed
  most of the work.
- But now I only need to get the ***application
  package name***.
- Their is a method

  > getPackageName(module: Module)
- This method takes module as a input But I don't know how to pass the module as input.
- My core requiremnet for this task is I want to create a directory in parent directory by stand in child directory.

***For example:***

I have four directories **A, B, C, D.**

A(parent) , B ( Child of A) , C (child of B) , D (Child of C).

let say I am standing in directory D and I want to create common directory (F) inside A along with B ( F sibling to B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the parent directory form srcOut like

```
fun getApplicationPackageFile(srcOut: File, applicationPackage: String): File {
    var applicationPackageFile = srcOut.path.toString()
    var pk = applicationPackage.replace(".", "\\")

    val status: Boolean = applicationPackageFile.contains(pk)
    return if (status) {
        var file =
            applicationPackageFile.substring(0, applicationPackageFile.indexOf(pk)) + pk + "\\"
        File(file)
    } else {
        srcOut
    }
}
```

And call it like

```
val pkFile = getApplicationPackageFile(srcOut, moduleData.projectTemplateData.applicationPackage)
```

So If you want to save some file to the core application package..

```
pkFile.resolve("AppViewModel.$ktOrJavaExt")
```

**For Linux and Mac**
Change above line to

```
var pk = applicationPackage.replace(".", "/")
```

Comment: I have this solution and I tested this on Linux, mac and windows but it only works on window.

Comment: @MuhammadIbrahim I have added solution for linux and Mac in Answer